# Configuring and Using Plymouth in Yocto-based Linux Distribution

Tags: embedded-linux, splash-screen, yocto, boot

I would like to use plymouth in yocto, however nowhere I can see involves some kind of a usage manual for plymouth in yocto. I am using an ARMv6-based Embedded device and would like to compile plymouth with yocto. As far as I know, Yocto does not involve initramfs by default, so I assumed I would do the following things in order to use plymouth-based splash screen in Yocto.

- Add `meta-initramfs` to `bblayers.conf`
- Add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "dracut plymouth"`

This runs and compiles perfectly. However, I cant see any splash screen, nor do I see any binary to use as initramfs manually.

Note that I already have a psplash package running as a splash screen.

```
IMAGE_FEATURES_append = "splash"
```

I would like to know how to configure Yocto so that I can use Plymouth.

Any pointers, guidance would help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit:** Now I'm able to generate initramfs images with plymouth included. The files that I can see are either named `*.cpio.gz` or `Image-..initramfs.bin`. I don't know which file to use and how to mount it.

Comment: Please try set `SPLASH = "plymouth"` though I didn't try it myself.

Comment: I did this already. Right now the problem is booting using a cpio.gz image, which I was not able to do unfortunately

Comment: Or a Image-initramfs.bin file, Im not sure which one I should use, with which  kernel command line parameter.

Comment: For myself, I add 'iso' to IMAGE_FSTYPES then boot the iso image with VirtualBox. :) BTW please make sure there is a space before splash in `IMAGE_FEATURES_append = "splash"`

Comment: I want to do this as well - have you figured it out?

Comment: I think dracut shouldn't be installed in the initramfs. But it should be built as a native tool, and be used for generating the initramfs(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/psplash = "plymouth" on your local.conf.